# JQuery how to implement the explode animation

Tags: jquery

I am attempting to use a demo from JQuery UI and I can't seem to be able to change the behavior from fadeIn to explode. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Here is what I have so far.

```
$item.explode(function() {
  var $list = $("ul", $trash ).length ?
    $("ul", $trash) :
    $("<ul class='playlist ui-helper-reset'/>").appendTo($trash);

  $item.explode(function(){
    $item
      .animate({ width: "190px" })
      .animate({ height: "20px" });
  });
});
```

What I'm after is to explode the items when they are moved to the trash and remove them completely remove them instead of appending them.

Comment: try  `$("#element").toggle("explode");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working by adding the following:

```
$(this).hide('explode', { "pieces":10 }, 1600, function() { $(this).remove; });
```

The complete function looks like this now:

```
  $item.explode(function(){
    $item
      .animate({ width: "190px" })
      .animate({ height: "20px" });
      $(this).hide('explode', { "pieces":10 }, 1600, function() { $(this).remove; });
  });
```